# Ruby regex: replace double slashes in URL

Tags: ruby, regex

I want to replace all multiple slashes in URL, apart from those in protocol definition ('http[s]://', 'ftp://' and etc). How do I do this?

This code replaces without any exceptions:

```
url.gsub(/\/\/+/, '/')
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You just need to exclude any match which is preceeded by `:`

```
url.gsub(/([^:])\/\//, '\1/')
```

Comment: Thank you, but how could I now prevent it from selecting the closest character from the left? http://rubular.com/r/PhVk4JSxcx

Comment: Use a negative lookbehind: `%r{(?<!:)//}` (not available in Ruby 1.8)

Comment: If you don't have negative lookbehind you can use a capture `url.gsub(/([^:])\/\//, '\1/')`

Comment: @Stuart, thanks I've updated my answer to use the back reference, since it's more widely compatible.

Comment: how about protocol-less urls like //www.domain.com/ used for http/https swaping?

Answer (score 2):

I tried using [URI](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/uri/rdoc/):

```
require "uri"
url = "http://host.com//foo//bar"
components = URI.split(url)
components[-4].gsub!(/\/+/, "/")
fixed_url = [components[0], "://", components[2], components[-4]].join
```

But that seemed hardly better than using a regex.

Answer (score 0):

`gsub` can take a block:

```
url = 'http://host.com//foo/bar'
puts url.gsub(%r{.//}) { |s| (s == '://') ? s : s[0] + '/' }
>> http://host.com/foo/bar
```

Or, as @Phrogz so kindly reminded us:

```
puts url.gsub(%r{(?<!:)//}, '/')
>> http://host.com/foo/bar
```